# How to make text in html perpendicularly?

Tags: html

Hey  I don't know how to make perpendicularly text in Html i tried this:

```html
<head>
<style>
 body {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform-origin: left top 0;
 background-color: red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>Hello World!</body>
```

But it just made red background color.
Can you help me ?

Comment: I hope that answers your question, if Yes please any of the questions [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate, don't do that affecting to body directly.

Make a class, for example 'vertical-container' and then apply the style there.

```
<head>
<style>
 body .vertical-container {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    background-color: red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vertical-container" > Hello World! </div>
</body>
```

Edit: Remember then that it element will have some inherited properties from the parent (body in this case) since it's relative positioned for default. So you could need 'play' with sizes ultil you have what you really want. For example giving a body height:100%, width:100% if what you want is full screen content.

Comment: I guess it's fine with the example. But may be helpful for large application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you DID achieve it, but pushed it off-canvas...

**Update:** After comment I am also demonstrating a -90 degree transform. Note that the superfluous positioning rules (especially "bottom") come about from having two paragraphs. But the point is that when you rotate something it can end up on canvas without some extra positioning.

```css
body {
  background-color: red
}

p.ninety {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

p.minusninety {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: -78px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="ninety">Hello World!</p>
  <p class="minusninety">I'm getting dizzy!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess if i will give there 270 it should be the other side?

Comment: @Anonymous 1582 Yes that's right, or -90 would work too. I just added that to the snippet with some notes.